# google drive: how to correctly set file type?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, mime-types

apparently there are two different 'file types' in gdrive. what's the difference between XXX and YYY? what values should i put in each of them?

```
File fileMetadata = new File()
                             .setParents(parentFolders)
                             .setMimeType(XXX)  <---------------------
                             .setName(filename);

drive.files()
    .create(fileMetadata, new InputStreamContent(YYY, content)) <----
    .execute();
```

Comment: Google drive supports many different mime types for files.  Can you clarify your question a bit?  The mime type `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` is important in that it distinguishes folders from non-folders (i.e. files).

Comment: where should i put this mime type? as XXX or YYY? and what should i put in the other one?

Comment: What is `fileMetadata`?  Is it a folder of file, and if the latter then what type of file?  What are you trying to stream in the second case?  You might do well to have a look at Google's examples (for either v2 or v3 of the Drive API depending on what you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the first part of your question.  If you want to create a new file on Google Drive from a local CSV file, then you should use the MIME type `text/csv`.  Here is what the code might look like using your example:

```
File fileMetadata = new File().setParents(parentFolders)
                              .setMimeType("text/csv")
                              .setName(filename);
```

The MIME type you use should always match the type of the actual local file.  If you set convert to true, then you can have your CSV file converted to a Google document.