# Create a Google Document with Google Drive API and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using Google Drive API V3 to manage my Google Drive with Node.js and google-api-nodejs-client v12.0.0 (http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/)

When I try to create a simple text/plain document, all work fine. But when I try to create a Google Document, Google Drive API return a 400 error with message "Bad Request".

```
/**
   * Create file on Google Drive
   * https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create
   */
  CreateFile: (googleapi, oauth2Client, fileName, fileContent, fileType) => {
    const DRIVE = googleapi.drive({ version: 'v3', auth: oauth2Client });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('fileType:',fileType);
      DRIVE.files.create({
        resource: {
          name: fileName,
          mimeType: fileType
        },
        media: {
          mimeType: fileType,
          body: fileContent
        }
      }, (err, result) => {
        if( err ) {
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
```

When the value of variable "fileType" is "text/plain", all is ok. But when  I put "application/vnd.google-apps.document" to the value, I got a 400 error.

Some solution ? :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request) of Drive API, The `error 400: Bad Request` can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.

This error can be thrown when trying to add a duplicate parent to a Drive item. It can also be thrown when trying to add a parent that would create a cycle in the directory graph.

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "badRequest",
"message": "Bad Request"
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Bad Request"
}
}
```

So in your case, the value that you provide in a field or parameter is invalid.

Check this SO question and some documentation to know more information about your issue.

- [google drive: how to correctly set file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181180/google-drive-how-to-correctly-set-file-type)
- https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types
- [Create Files using NODE.JS](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-create)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you, I`m using V4 of Google Drive API

```
        var fileMetadata = {
            'name': 'Project plan',
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
        };

        drive.files.create({
            resource: fileMetadata,
            fields: '*',
            auth: jwtClient
        }, function (err, file) {
            if (err) {
                return global.triggerError(req, res, err);
            }

            drive.permissions.create({
                resource: {
                    'type': 'anyone',
                    'role': 'writer'
                },
                fileId: file.id,
                fields: 'id',
                auth: jwtClient
            }, function (err, permission) {
                if (err) {
                    return global.triggerError(req, res, err);
                }

                callback(file);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different mime types:

```
{
  requestBody: {
    ...
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
  },

  media: {
    ... 
    mimeType: 'text/html', // or text/plain
  }
}
```