# Create a Google Document with a built-in object using Node

Tags: node.js, google-docs

I've seen the post below on how to create a Google doc instance using Node.

[Create a Google Document with Google Drive API and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703265/create-a-google-document-with-google-drive-api-and-node-js][1])

But I also want to pass through an object so when the google doc gets created, it has that object stored in its environment. Is there a way to do so by passing the object through one of the parameters below?

```
DRIVE.files.create({
        resource: {
          name: fileName,
          mimeType: fileType
        },
        media: {
          mimeType: fileType,
          body: fileContent
        }
      }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to create new Google Document using googleapis with Node.js. At that time, you want to put some texts to the Google Document. Is my understanding correct? And, in your script, have you already been able to create new Google Document?

Comment: What do you mean by `I also want to pass through an object so when the google doc gets created, it has that object stored in its environment`?

Comment: @Tanaike not quite. I want the object to be stored in Google Doc app script. Say in Node, I have an object  var obj = { “foo”:”bar”}. When Node creates a new google doc instance, I want it to write the same object in the google doc app script. So when I open that google doc and I go to its script editor, { “foo”: “bar”}  is already there. 

Hope this clarifies things a bit. Thank you both for reviewing my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to create new Google Document by including Google Apps Script as the container-bound script.

  - As a sample situation, you want to include the script of `var obj = { “foo”:”bar”}`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, in order to achieve this, I used the methods of projects.create and projects.updateContent in Google Apps Script API.

#### Flow:

The flow of this answer is as follows.

1. Create new Google Document.
2. Create new GAS project as the container-bound script to the created Google Document.
3. Put the script to the created GAS project.

#### Preparation:

Before you run the script, please prepare as follows.

1. Please enable Google Apps Script API at API console.

   - From your question, I thought that you have already enabled Drive API at API console.
2. Please set the scopes of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects`.
3. Please remove the credential file including the access token and refresh token. Because this way is used for reflecting the new scopes to the access token. When you run the script after the credential file was removed, the authorization process is run. So please retrieve the code and retrieve the access token and refresh token using the code.
4. Please prepare a sample text file as the filename of `sample.txt`. Because `media` is used in your script.

#### Sample script:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
const script = google.script({ version: "v1", auth });

drive.files.create(
  {
    requestBody: {
      name: "sampleDocument",
      mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
    },
    media: {
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      body: fs.createReadStream("./sample.txt")
    }
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    script.projects.create(
      {
        requestBody: {
          title: "sampleGASProject",
          parentId: res.data.id
        }
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        script.projects.updateContent(
          {
            scriptId: res.data.scriptId,
            auth,
            resource: {
              files: [
                {
                  name: "Code",
                  type: "SERVER_JS",
                  source: 'var obj = {"foo":"bar"}\n'
                },
                {
                  name: "appsscript",
                  type: "JSON",
                  source:
                    '{"timeZone":"America/New_York","exceptionLogging":"STACKDRIVER"}'
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log("Done.");
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
);
```

- When you run this sample script, new Google Document is created as the filename of `sampleDocument` and new GAS project is created as the project name of `sampleGASProject`.

  - After the script was finished, you can see new Google Document at the root folder. When you open the Google Document and open the script editor, you can see the script of `var obj = {"foo":"bar"}`.

#### Note:

- If you are using the service account, unfortunately, GAS project cannot be managed with the service account. Please be careful this. So please use OAuth2.

#### References:

- [Method: projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create)
- [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)

In my environment, I could confirm that the sample script works. But if that didn't work in your environment, I apologize. At that time, please check whether API is enabled and/or other environment. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the thorough response! I am going to try this out in the coming days and keep you posted the progress. Can't thank you enough for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @Drive2blue Thank you for replying. In my environment, I could confirm that the sample script works. But if that didn't work in your environment, I apologize.

Comment: This worked like magic!! You are a genius, sir! Thank you so much again for the concrete, intuitive advice.

Comment: @Drive2blue Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.